# SwiftUI - condition in tabItem breaks EnvironmentObject

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabs

**Why EnvironmentObject doesn't work when there is a condition inside TabView?**

I want to make a simple condition: if a tab is selected render icon as fill, if not selected - render as outline:

```
selectedTab == "first" ? Image(systemName: "star.fill") : Image(systemName: "star")
```

This code works, but it breaks EnvironmentObject I'm using.
EnvironmentObject works normal when I delete condition inside TabView and just use:

```
Image(systemName: "star")
```

Here is a simple example. EnvironmentObject is used to change number across both Views. When I don't use a condition inside TabView, number is changing as expected on both views. When I use condition inside TabView, -/+ buttons stop working after changing tabs and numbers are not the same on both views.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug in SwiftUI?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var selectedNumber: Number
    @State var selectedTab: String = "first"
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            
            FirstView()
                .tabItem {
                    //Image(systemName: "star") // Changing numbers works
                    selectedTab == "first" ? Image(systemName: "star.fill") : Image(systemName: "star") // Changing numbers doesn't work
                    Text("First")
                }
                .tag("first")
            
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Second")
                }
                .tag("second")
        }
        .environmentObject(Number())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(Number())
    }
}


struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DateView()
            Text("First View")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DateView()
            Text("Second View")
        }
    }
}

class Number: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedMonth: Int = 1
}

struct DateView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var selectedNumber: Number
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "minus")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .background(Color.black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedNumber.selectedMonth = selectedNumber.selectedMonth - 1
                    
                }
            
            Text("\(selectedNumber.selectedMonth)")
                .frame(width: 50)
            
            Image(systemName: "plus")
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .background(Color.black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedNumber.selectedMonth = selectedNumber.selectedMonth + 1
                }
            
        }
        .background(Color.gray)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `.environmentObject` line from inside `ContentView`  The environment should come from outside the view as you have done with the preview.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can I continue to use EnvironmentObject? Is StateObject replacement of EnvironmentObject. I've started thinking that maybe I should use StateObject instead, but with your update it works with EnvironmentObject

Comment: After reading more (and trying few things), I think you that your answer is the best solution in my case. Would you mind sending it as an Answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1):

try this, if you want to start the environmentObject from within ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var selectedNumber: Number = Number()
    @State var selectedTab: String = "first"
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            
            FirstView()
                .tabItem {
                  //  Image(systemName: "star") // Changing numbers works
                    selectedTab == "first" ? Image(systemName: "star.fill") : Image(systemName: "star") // Changing numbers works
                    Text("First")
                }
                .tag("first")
            
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                    Text("Second")
                }
                .tag("second")
        }
        .environmentObject(selectedNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I don't understand something. I've read that "You should use `@StateObject` only once per object, which should be in whichever view is responsible for creating the object. All other views that share your object should use `@ObservedObject`." So I was thinking I should use `@StateObject` in DateView, not ContentView. And ContentView should have `@EnvironmentObject`. But it doesn't work like that.

Comment: yes, you read correctly, with the caveat, that ".... All other views (AFTER THAT) that share ...". So, "@StateObject" needs to be at the start of your hierarchy, and "@ObservedObject" after that. And so you have to put "@StateObject" in ContentView or before that (as @Paulw11 mentioned) and pass it using ".environmentObject(..)".

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks :) While your solution works in this case, I think that what will work better for me is the answer from @Paulw11. If I would use this number counter from my example on few pages independently, I would probably need StateObject on first view per page. To create independent instances of these counters. But in my app I need one counter to have the same number on all pages, so probably sticking to EnvironmentObject is a better way in my case. If I understand it correctly. Thanks for help! I've learned a lot.

Comment: I think that what you wrote in previous comment would also work. _you have to put "@StateObject" in ContentView or before that (as @Paulw11 mentioned) and pass it using ".environmentObject(..)"_
What made me confused is that I was thinking that StateObject and EnvironmentObject are 2 separate things. But I can use StateObject before ContentView and pass it as environmentObject